# Counting JSON, NSArray

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa

I got a small problem i got a JSON feed like

```
 [
    {
        id: "7",
        title: "",

    },
    id: "8",
    title: ""
}
]
```

Now i want to count al 'objects' in my JSON i tried;

Comment: can you show the @property declaration of tableData

Comment: @VolureDarkAngel i edited the first post

Comment: I have put up a couple of things for you to take a look at.

Comment: That's invalid JSON.  And the number of "objects" would equal the number of NSDictionarys created, if you're using the JSON definition of "object".

Comment: It's still invalid - you have named members outside an object.  I would suggest you need another "{" after the first "},"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all your feed looks invalid.

```
[
    {
        id: "7",
        title: "",

    },
    id: "8",
    title: ""

}// Still Too many Braces.
]
```

Other than that, your code looks functional..

**Edit**

Nope, NSBum is right. data should not be a count.

```
[self setTableData:array];
```

Also, after viewDidAppear, you should call -[UITableView reloadData] on the tableview that is requesting. It may have called for its data before you set the tableData variable.

also, you should be calling for information on the property rather than the ivar

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    NSLog(@"x: %u", [self.tableData count]);
    return [self.tableData count];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your `tableData` ivar is an `NSArray`.  I think you want:

```
[self setTableData:array];
```

You're getting a hint with the error about setting an `NSUInteger` to an `NSArray` ivar

Comment: Thanks, but when i NSLog array it's printing my whole JSON and the NSLog `    NSLog(@"x: %u", [tableData count]);
` its returing 0

Comment: Then I suppose we need to see your property declaration or setter for `tableData` as @Volure DarkAngel suggested.